# How can I get a binary video for bubble detection using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to get a binary video for bubble detection but my output is saved as a python source file not .mp4. What should I do?

```
import cv2
from cv2 import VideoCapture

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r'C:\Users\Harshali Kulkarmi\OneDrive\Desktop\WASEDA UNI CLASSES\LAB WORK\Embolism research\videos\MAH00207.mp4')
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()


while True:
    # Read a frame from the video stream
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        break

    # Apply background subtraction to the current frame
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

    # Display the foreground mask
    cv2.imshow('Foreground Mask', fgmask)

    # Exit if 'q' is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the video stream and destroy all windows
```

I keep getting frame .py output. Also, how can I make this clearer?

thon/python.exe" "c:/Users/Harshali Kulkarmi/OneDrive/Desktop/WASEDA UNI CLASSES/LAB WORK/Embolism research/videos/video frames/207/notes.py"

General configuration for OpenCV 4.7.0 =====================================
Version control:               4.7.0

Extra modules:
Location (extra):            D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv_contrib/modules
Version control (extra):     4.7.0

Platform:
Timestamp:                   2023-02-22T13:20:15Z
Host:                        Windows 10.0.17763 AMD64
CMake:                       3.24.2
CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015
CMake build tool:            MSBuild.exe
MSVC:                        1900
Configuration:               Debug Release

CPU/HW features:
Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
requested:                 SSE3
Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
AVX2 (32 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

C/C++:
Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
C++ standard:                11
C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24245.0)
C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP   /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /INCREMENTAL:NO  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /debug /INCREMENTAL  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
ccache:                      NO
Precompiled headers:         YES
Extra dependencies:          wsock32 comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32
3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf zlib quirc ippiw ippicv

OpenCV modules:
To be built:                 aruco barcode bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio videostab wechat_qrcode xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
Disabled:                    world
Disabled by dependency:      -
Unavailable:                 alphamat cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv freetype hdf java julia matlab ovis python2 sfm ts viz
Applications:                -
Documentation:               NO
Non-free algorithms:         NO

Windows RT support:            NO

GUI:                           WIN32UI
Win32 UI:                    YES
VTK support:                 NO

Media I/O:
ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.13)
JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
SIMD Support Request:      YES
SIMD Support:              NO
WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
HDR:                         YES
SUNRASTER:                   YES
PXM:                         YES
PFM:                         YES

Video I/O:
DC1394:                      NO
FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
GStreamer:                   NO
DirectShow:                  YES
Media Foundation:            YES
DXVA:                      YES

Parallel framework:            Concurrency

Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

Other third-party libraries:
Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
at:                   D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
at:                D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
Lapack:                      NO
Eigen:                       NO
Custom HAL:                  NO
Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
Include path:                D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
Link libraries:              Dynamic load

Python 3:
Interpreter:                 C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/python.exe (ver 3.7.9)
Libraries:                   C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/libs/python37.lib (ver 3.7.9)
numpy:                       C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.17.0)
install path:                python/cv2/python-3

Python (for build):            C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/python2.7.exe

Java:
ant:                         NO
JNI:                         C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.362-9/x64/include C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.362-9/x64/include/win32 C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.362-9/x64/include
Java wrappers:               NO
Java tests:                  NO

Install to:                    D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-install[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FhAb.jpg)

Comment: Can you please add examples for frame .py output that you are getting? Also, please edit your question to be formatted correctly. Maybe something is wrong with your OpenCV version. Add `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())` to the beginning of your code, and add all the printed information to your question.

Comment: Hi I added print(cv2.getBuildInformation()) and I got the above information. Do you thinkk there is anything wrong with my opencv version?

Comment: I am trying to add the .py output, I am sorry it's my first time using python, I am not sure how I can add files instead of text.

Comment: @Rotem I am trying to add the .py output, I am sorry it's my first time using python, I am not sure how I can add files instead of text.

Comment: Are you sure this is all the output of `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())`? Where are all the C++ flags? I don't understand the meaning of *"I keep getting frame .py output"*. I thought the output is in text format, is it an image (there is an option to post an image)? I also don't understand the meaning of *"how can I make this clearer?"*. Making what clearer?  Note: You forgot to call `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` at the end.

Comment: @Rotem sorry I thought it was too long and would be troublesome to read, so I edited some build information. I have added the full version now. The image I added shows binary.py file which when opened, plays the video. By 'making it clearer' I meant- background visual noise removal. I tried a code on an image but the result still had some noise.

Comment: The OpenCV build is looking fine. You may remove the build information from the question. For asking about clearer "background visual noise removal", you better add some better images. Add image before and after `fgbg.apply(frame)` and explain which part should be clearer. (add sample images from `MAH00207.mp4` before and after `fgbg.apply(frame)`)

Comment: @Rotem I have added an image after applying MOG2. I took a screenshot of the python file playing and saved it as an jpg. I have added it to the question?

Comment: I recommend you to add an image before `fgbg.apply(frame)` and image after `fgbg.apply(frame)`. There is no reason to take a screenshot - add `cv2.imwrite('orig_frame.png', frame)` and `cv2.imwrite('fgmask.png', fgmask)`. Please note that I probably can't answer your question anyway.

Comment: @Rotem thank you for your help! I tried fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v') and it worked! The output is still not satisfactory, but definitely a step in the right direction. Thank you again for trying to help :)